# Copy a row to the row of the macro button

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried this as an intermediate step and it works:

```
Sub Test_v1()
Sheets("Code").Range("A2").EntireRow.Copy Range("A5")
End Sub
```

The code above always copies to row 5. I want it to copy to the row where the macro-button is currently in. I have tried this and it does not work work:

```
Sub Test_v2()
Sheets("Code").Range("A2").EntireRow.Copy ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
End Sub
```

Supposedly TopLeftCell returns a Range. Then why does this not work? And how can I make it work?

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work? Is there an error? Do remember, your button's `TopLeftCell` has to be column A otherwise ranges wont be of the same size and will return an error. If you button is in any other column then use something like: `Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row)`. Note that the use of `ActiveSheet` or implicit sheet references are not optimum in itself either.

Comment: Yes, it threw an error. I don't understand the point about column "A". Why is ActiveSheet or implicit reference not good?

Comment: The point about the importance of column A is simple. let's say we have a row of 10 blocks like `■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ` and we try to lift these blocks up and put it in an empty row that has place for 10 blocks like `□ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □`... yey, that works. Now what happens if we try to put these ten blocks in a place where there is only place for 7 of them `□ □ □ □ □ □ □`.....Oops, that won't fit! It's the same with cells in a row. You copy a ***whole*** row of cells, and if you are trying to place those in another row that is ***not*** the same size it will return an error.

Comment: @JodV, Thank you that explained it very well also for Dummies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, please (if your button is a sheet Form type):

```
 Sheets("Code").Range("A2").EntireRow.Copy _
   Cells(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row, "A")
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants to copy that row. He wants to *paste* into the row of the `TopLeftCell` of the clicked button. Notice that the `Range` to paste values towards can be behind the `Copy` statement (as in the given example).

Comment: @FaneDuru: It works, it is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much! Can you explain what I did wrong and you did right?

Comment: @Usal: Glad I could help you! In such cases, we here tick the code left side check box in order to make it the **accepted answer**. If somebody else will  look for something similar, he will know that the answer code works...